# Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'url_launcher_ios' not found

Tags: ios, flutter, url-launcher

i'm trying to using package: url_launcher of flutter to make call.
my project working til well and when i install url_launcher i got error like this

Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'url_launcher_ios' not found

my flutter doctor fine

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-arm, locale en-VN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.65.2)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

some way i also try

`flutter clean & flutter pub get`

`pod update repo && pod install`

[image: this is log when i build in Xcode]

Comment: i check podfile.lock 

it's just have 2 line 

PODFILE CHECKSUM: 2fb48e2e296f814d39edd589c5ae762824b0f3c4

COCOAPODS: 1.11.3

Comment: a simple `pod install` fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Close Xcode
- Check if your minimum deployed version in the pod file is not commented
- Check if the package scheme is added in the info.plist file, here.

  `<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key> <array> <string>sms</string> <string>tel</string> </array>`
- Use the lastest version of the package (which is 6.1.7) (as of the date of this answer).

Do and run the following

- Delete the pubspec.lock file in the project app directory.

`flutter clean`

`flutter pub get`

In the ios directory, run
`pod install` & `pod install --repo-update`